# Have I commited disbelief?

Tags: islamic-basis, shirk

I was reading a book COMPLETELY NOT RELATED TO ASTROLOGY WHATSOEVER , ACCIDENTLY  read something which said such and such a thing is an astrological sign 
Does that mean that I have learnt astrology and committed disbelief ?

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of disbelief is belief.

So do you believe what you've read is true?
If yes your belief is the opposite of what a Muslim should believe in and therefore it will be regarded as disbelief or maybe shirk if you considered both Allah's rules and what you've learnt about the astrological signs as (parts of) the truth.

It is rather frowned upon to read what may cause doubts in your religion (faith) or shirk or disbelief. Some scholars would consider this even haram for a person who is not strong in his/her faith. Therefore it is recommended to seek refuge by Allah and repent from what you've did no matter if the answer of the above question was "yes" or "no". However if it was "yes" you should even repent more sincerely and avoid doing this again.

Comment: I read it in a book that was NOT REALTED TO ASTROLOGY WHATSOEVER but I did not expect to encounter it

Comment: @Staranimator and??? Does this change anything about it being a reason to repent? No the prophet used to say astaghfiruallah 70 times (in some ahadith 100times) in an encounter what hinders you to do the same?

Comment: The answer is no . I absolutely do not believe what I read is true . But does that mean that I have learnt it.

Comment: Because sometimes even sheikhs scholars explain how magicians do their magic just to make people aware that doing that is haram but they do not believe in it right ????

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to know the evil to fight it, but this requires a certain solid basic knowledge. That's why scholars may say "topic x" is haram even if they themselves may have a certain contribution in it (for example philosophy). This means it is haram for a layman or a person who has a low level of faith and iman as they may lose their faith! But a scholar who knows his religion well might try to learn ways to refute it based on its own principles. And hopefully many scholars have knowledge and life experience to help people and guide them.